# SQL query to compare 2 columns and output 1 if one is greater than the other

Tags: sql

I have a table called product_pairs, which has the following

```
product_pair, product_views_1, product_views_2
```

I would like to write a query that will effectively output a new table with following columns

```
product_pair, comparison_indicator
```

Where comparison_indicator = 1 if product_views_1 > product_views_2 and comparison_indicator = 0 otherwise.

I am currently using a simple query that is something like

```
SELECT product_pair, CASE WHEN product_views_1 > product_views_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as comparison_indicator  

FROM product_pairs
```

However this seems to lead to errors.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: What kind of errors are you having?

Comment: You didn't specify the RDBMS.  Maybe the one you are using does not support case constructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the query runs in the your SQL engine, the only possible problem that I can think of from such a simple query is that `product_views_2` is `NULL` and you want the expression to return `1` instead of `0`:

```
SELECT product_pair,
       (CASE WHEN coalesce(product_views_1, 0) > coalesce(product_views_2, 0) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END) as comparison_indicator
FROM product_pairs;
```

Comparisons involving `NULL` are always false -- with the exception of `is NULL`, of course.

Answer (score -3):

This should work

```
SELECT 'product_pair' = CASE WHEN product_views_1 > product_views_2 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as comparison_indicator  

FROM product_pairs
```

Comment: If you want to quote an alias, you have to use double quotes, not single.  Also, Berk U wants to select the product_pair field and your answer does not do that.